# Model chaining not setting ID, is this normal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: `User`, `Song`, `Album`

A `User` `has_many :songs, :albums`

A `Song` `belongs_to :user, :album`

A `Album` `belongs_to :user, has_many :songs`

When I do something like the following:

```
user = User.find(:first)
album = user.albums.find(:first)
album.songs.create(params)
```

It will work fine and create a new `Song` with the foreign key `album_id` set correctly, but it won't set the `user_id` of the song to the `User` who created it. Is this normal? How can I create a new `Song` and make sure it applies both the `album_id` and the `user_id`?

I guess I could just have a User create a `Song` and then choose an `Album` to add it to?

Answer (score 0):

There is no chaining with the user there.
You instantiated an album object which has an user_id set to that user, but that doesn't mean ActiveRecord will automatically set that exact user_id to the created songs for that album. That would be really unexpected behaviour for most applications.

In your case you could pass the user to the create method

Something like:

```
album.songs.create(params.merge({:user => user}))
```

Anyway, that sounds like it should be refactored. Where are you calling that code, is in the song create action? Which are the exact params you get from the request, why aren't you using params[:song] for the create attributes?